# Вставка после X параграфов

Tags: jquery, insert, ads

Салют! Есть такой код для вставки Гугла после 3-го параграфа.

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#content-middle p:eq(3)").after('<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="text-align:center;display: block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx" data-ad-slot="xxx" data-ad-format="auto">')}).ready(function(){(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).push({})});
```

Но, если вверху идёт таблица, тогда вставка идёт либо в tr либо td. Подскажите есть ли вариант сделать вставку после таблицы, либо запретить исполнение скрипта... Спасибо!

Очень сильно портит визуальное впечатление о сайте.

Answer (score 2):

если как-то можно однозначно идентифицировать таблицу после которой вставлять, то можно же проверочку перед вставкой сделать, а-ля

```
$('body').find('селектор для таблицы').length >0
```

после чего после таблицы использовать .next()

UDP 1.: попробуйте так
UDP 2.: еще поправил

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var pArr = $("#content-middle p");
  var p = pArr[2]; // индекс начинается с 0  
  var parent = $(p).parent();
  var parentTagName = $(parent).prop("tagName")
  if(parentTagName != 'TD')
    $(p).after('<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="text-align:center;display: block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx" data-ad-slot="xxx" data-ad-format="auto">')
})
// закомментил чтобы работало на stackoverflow.com
//.ready(function(){(adsbygoogle=window.adsbygoogle||[]).push({})});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-middle">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>параграф 1</p>
  <p>параграф 2</p>
  <table>
    <tr>  
      <td>
        <p>параграф 3</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но к сожалению такой возможности нет...(

Comment: ну хорошо, можно пойти от обратного, есть ли какие-то другие закономерности. при которых на некоторых страницах есть таблица перед параграфами? м.б. url-адрес (одни и те же get-параметры), другие элементы на странице (их наличие/отсутствие)?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Всё что в принципе есть из других элементов это - h1. То есть структура иногда такая - h1 - p - p - table (в таблице идут параграфы и туда выполняеться скрипт), либо - h1 - p - table и т.д. А чаще всего - h1 - p - p - p. Спасибо... Надеюсь что-то можно придумать.

Comment: Добавил в ответ кусок кода, попробуйте. Не забудьте раскомментить последнюю строку у себя

Comment: К сожалению Ваше решение не работает... Всё осталось как было.

Comment: изменил, перепроверьте

Comment: Теперь работает. Но выдается та же ошибка что и в предложенном решении ниже, только где есть таблица, а не параграф.

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерная логика - если попали в таблицу, то ставим после неё, если не попали, то оставляем как есть:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selector = $("#content-middle p:eq(3)");
    if ($(selector).closest('table')) {
        selector = $(selector).closest('table');
    }
    selector.after('<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="text-align:center;display: block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx" data-ad-slot="xxx" data-ad-format="auto">');
    setTimeout(function(){
        adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}) 
    }, 1000);
});
```

Только в верстке выше не должно быть таблиц (либо нужно задать селектор для таблицы)

Comment: Работает, вставка идёт после таблицы. Но не работает после параграфов. Когда структура - h1 - p - p - p...
http://www.picshare.ru/view/8208168/ - Скриншот.

Comment: Логику добавления параграфов я не трогал, у вас ошибка гугл рекламы - говорит что все блоки с рекламой уже заполнены. попробуйте запустить его с таймаутом, поправил в ответе.

Comment: Тоже самое, гугл думает что всё занято... И у Вас не хватает ( перед adsbygoogle.